Ho to show default avatar when avatar field is empty or file not found?
In a Laravel 10 / Nova 4.27 app, I have an avatar field defined in the User resource:
Image::make(__('Avatar'), 'avatar')
    ->disk('local')
    ->path('public/avatars')
    ->prunable()
    ->deletable(true),

How can I display a default avatar located in public/img when the avatar field is empty or the file is not found?

Try using the resolveUsing() method
Image::make(__('Avatar'), 'avatar')
    ->disk('local')
    ->path('public/avatars')
    ->prunable()
    ->deletable(true)
    ->resolveUsing(function ($value) {
        // Check if the avatar exists
        if ($value && Storage::disk('local')->exists("public/avatars/{$value}")) {
            return "avatars/{$value}";
        }

        // Return the default image if the avatar is missing
        return 'avatars/default.jpg';
   }),

This can also be done with Laravel Nova's built-in avatar field: Laravel\Nova\Fields\Avatar
